# Easy Lim Sup Proof?

Tags: limits, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

Let $x_n$ and $y_n$ be bounded sequences such that $x_n \leq y_n$ for all $n$. Show $\limsup(x_n)\leq \limsup(y_n)$

$x_n \leq y_n$ for all $n$, so $\sup(x_n) \leq \sup(y_n)$ for all $n$.

As this holds for all $n$, $\limsup(x_n)\leq \limsup(y_n)$

This seems too simple to me. I tried to do this with the $\epsilon$ definition of limits, but I struggle with this strategy. Any clarification or verification is appreciated.

Comment: Proof looks good to me.

Comment: What does $\sup(x_n)$ means ? Why (using your notation), $\sup(x_n)\leq \sup(y_n)$ ?

Comment: $sup (x_n) \geq x_n$ for all $n$

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the definition of the limit superior:
$$ \limsup_n x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl(\sup_{k\ge n} x_k\bigr)=\inf_{\vphantom{\ge^l}   n}\bigl(\sup_{k\ge n} x_k\bigr). $$
Now set $a_n=\sup_{k\ge n} x_k$, $b_n=\sup_{k\ge n} y_k$. Since $x_k\le y_k$ for all $k$, we deduce that
$$a_n=\sup_{k\ge n} x_k\le b_n=\sup_{k\ge n} y_k, \enspace\text{whence }\enspace \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\le\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n.$$